# Tomcat 404 error after calling the web services

Tags: linux, nginx, tomcat, java, web-services

For the first time, I want to deploy a java web application in tomcat9 (On the Linux OS). I have successfully deployed it and tomcat is running. Also, on the browser, the index.jsp page is shown correctly. But when I try to call the application web services (using a login button), it gives 404 error.

Here is a part of the LoginController class:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/v1/security/login")
@CheckAccess(pricingPlanName = PricingPlanName.LOGIN)
public ResponseEntity<List<LoginResponseDTO>> login(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequestDTO loginRequestDTO) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(loginService.loginWithUserName(loginRequestDTO, localeUtil.getLocale(loginRequestDTO.getLang()), false), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

And here is the error text:

> HTTP Status 404 (Not Found) - **Description**: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
> (Apache Tomcat/9.0.71)

Can anyone one help me to solve this error?